# Result in show in column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It does not show the result in the column, and I am always informed of this error: Exception: Range not found myfunction @ Código.gs:12. I don't understand where the problem is. I tried several methods and failed. I changed the code several times and I couldn't. I searched a lot on the site, but I didn't find a solution. I tried to solve it and I didn't find something to solve this problem.

```js
function minhaFuncao() {
    // Gets the active worksheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
    // Gets the name of the tab where the result will be written
    var sheetName = "TERÇA";
  
    // Gets the tab with the specified name
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
    // Defines a cell range that includes all desired tabs
    var range = ss.getRange("JANEIRO!A5:C,FEVEREIRO!A5:C,'MARÇO'!A5:C,ABRIL!A5:C,MAIO!A5:C,JUNHO!A5:C,JULHO!A5:C,AGOSTO!A5:C,SETEMBRO!A5:C,OUTUBRO!A5:C,NOVEMBRO!A5:C,DEZEMBRO!A5:C");
  
    // Gets values ​​from cell range
    var data = range.getValues();
  
    // Defines the query to be executed
    var query = "select Col1 where dayOfWeek(Col3) = 3";
  
    // Run the query and get the results
    var queryResults = SpreadsheetApp.newFilter().setRange(range).whenFormulaSatisfied(query).getRange().getValues();
  
    // Creates a regular expression from the value in cell A2 on the worksheet
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() + "$");
  
    // Reduce the array of values ​​into a single sum by filtering out values ​​that match the regular expression
    var count = queryResults.flat().filter(cell => regex.test(cell)).reduce((acc, val) => acc + (val === "" ? 0 : Number(val)), 0);
  
    // Sets the result to the sum of matching values ​​or an empty string if no values ​​match
    var result = count > 0 ? count : "";
  
    // Gets the "TERÇA" tab of the worksheet
    var tuesdaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("TERÇA");
  
    // Sets cells A2 to A100 in the "TERÇA" tab as the result
    tuesdaySheet.getRange("A2:A100").setValue(result);
  }
```

Comment: You should consider turn this into a [rangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String)) and then you will a little more work to do.  Each range needs to be a separate string in A1 Notation

Comment: Actually I might actually consider just using a loop method and loop through an array of sheets

Comment: @Cooper Hi unfortunately it didn't work:
  var rangeList = ["JANEIRO!A5:C", "FEVEREIRO!A5:C".map(range => ss.getRange(range));

 
  var range = rangeList.reduce((acc, val) => acc.merge(val));

  
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  var query = "select Col1 where dayOfWeek(Col3) = 3";

  var queryResults = SpreadsheetApp.newFilter().setRange(range).whenFormulaSatisfied(query).getRange().getValues();
  var regex = new RegExp("^" + sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() + "$");

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation.  It looks like your making up your own methods.  Unfortunately, they are not in my documentation so they make no sense to me.

Comment: @AdelsonSiqueira please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function justastart() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const names = ["JANEIRO", "FEVEREIRO", "MARÇ", "ABRIL", "MAIO", "JUNHO", "JULHO", "AGOSTO", "SETEMBRO", "OUTUBRO", "NOVEMBRO", "DEZEMBRO"];
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("TERÇA");
  let arr = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~names.indexOf(sh.getName())).map(sh => sh.getRange("A5:C" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues());
  //arr is an array of 2d arrays with all of your data
}
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it did not work with code: https://jsbin.com/joloxarumu/edit?js,output

Comment: It's just a start you need to finish it

Comment: Please help me to terminal. I tried everything and I just failed

Comment: Okay, but first you must explain what you want done because I don't wish to read your code.

Comment: Without reading my code you will never understand what I want. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Well keep in mind that your code is currently incorrect

Comment: There is no method newFilter in class SpreadsheetApp

Comment: I updated the code: https://jsbin.com/zeroxol/edit?js,output following your suggestion, and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Oh well I guess you still have more work to do.